# как получить name в discord py

Tags: python

Пишу бота и мне нужно узнать каналы, которые есть в категории.
при

```
category = discord.utils.get(guild.categories, id=751053894238470244)
print(category.channels)
```

выдает

`[<VoiceChannel id=751085283776266272 name='z' position=8 bitrate=64000 user_limit=0 category_id=751053894238470244>, <VoiceChannel id=751085807388983379 name='z' position=9 bitrate=64000 user_limit=0 category_id=751053894238470244>, <VoiceChannel id=751086149317165066 name='z1' position=10 bitrate=64000 user_limit=0 category_id=751053894238470244>]`
И как вернуть name?

Comment: В данном случае у вас возвращается массив VoiceChannel объектов, что выдаст к примеру print(category.channels[0].name) ?

Comment: Хорошо. Это работает. Но как вернуть все name, а не только 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот код (ответ к коментарию). На выходе получим массив с именами.

```
names = [channel.name for channel in category.channels]
```